# Selective Reading From a Queue--Custom MSMQ Service, ESB, or Something Else?

Tags: c#, msmq, nservicebus, esb

Looking for some ideas/pattern to solve a design problem for a system I will be starting work on soon.  There is no question that I will need to use some sort of messaging (probably MSMQ) to communicate between certain areas of the system. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but at the same time I want to make sure I am using the right tool for the job.  I have been tinkering with and reading up on NServiceBus, and I'm very impressed with what it does--however I'm not sure it's intended for what I'm trying to achieve.

Here is a (hopefully) very simple and conceptual description of what the system needs to do:

I have a service that clients can send messages to.  The service is "Fire and Forget"--the most the client would get back is something that may say success or failure (success being that the message was received).

The handling/processing of each message is non-trivial, and may take up significant system resources.  For this reason only X messages can be handled concurrently, where X is a configurable value (based on system specs, etc.).  Incoming messages will be stored in queue until it's "their turn" to be handled.

For each client, messages must be handled in order (FIFO).  However, some clients may send many messages in succession (thousands or more), for example if they lost connectivity for a period of time.  For this reason, messages must be handled in a round-robin fashion across clients--no client is allowed to gorge and no client is allowed to starve.  So the system will either have to be able to query the queue for a specific client, or create separate queues per client (automatically, since the clients won't be known at compile time) and pull from them in rotation.

My current thinking is that I really just need to use vanilla MSMQ, create a service to accept messages and write them to one or more queues, then create a process to read messages from the queue(s) and handle/process them.  However, the reliability, auditing, scaleability, and ease of configuration you get with something like NServicebus looks very appealing.

Is an ESB the wrong tool for the job?  Is there some other technology or pattern I should be looking at?

**Update**

A few clarifications.

Regarding processing messages "in order"--in the context of a single client, the messages absolutely need to be processed in the order they are received.  It's complicated to explain the exact reasons why, but this is a firm requirement.  I neglected to mention that only one message per client would ever be processed concurrently.  So even if there were 10 worker threads and only one client had messages waiting to be processed, only one of those messages would be processed at a time--there would be no worry of a race condition.

I believe this is generally possible with vanilla MSMQ--that you can have a list of messages in a queue and always take the oldest one first.

I also wanted to clarify a use case for the round robin ordering.  In this example, I have two clients (A and B) who send messages, and only one worker thread.  All queues are empty.  Client A has lost connectivity overnight, so at 8am sends 1000 messages to the service.  These messages get queued up and the worker thread takes the oldest one and starts processing it.  As this first message is being processed, client B sends a message into the service, which gets queued up (as noted, probably in a separate queue).  When Client A's first message completes processing, the logic should check whether client B has a message (it's client B's "turn"), and since it finds one, process it next.

If client B hadn't sent a message during that time, the worker would continue processing client A's messages one at a time, always checking after processing to see if other client queues contained waiting messages to ensure that no client was being starved.

Where I still feel there may be a mismatch between an ESB and this problem is that an ESB is designed to facilitate communication between services; what I am trying to achieve is a combination of messaging/communication and a selective queuing system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the system will either have to be
>   able to query the queue for a specific client,

Searching through an MSMQ queue for a message from a particular client using cursors can be inefficient and doesn't scale.

> or create separate queues per client (automatically, since the
>   clients won't be known at compile time) and pull from them in rotation.

MSMQ cannot create queues automatically. All messages have to be sent to a known queue first. Your own custom dispatcher service, though, could then create new queues on demand and put copies of the messages in them.

[[I avoid saying "move" messages as you can't do that with application code; you can only read a message and create a new message using the original data. This distinction is important when you are using Source Journaling, for example.]]

Cheers

John Breakwell

Comment: Yep, I was pretty sure that searching through a queue was not a good option, especially when there are tens of thousands of messages.  I was thinking more along the lines of the service creating them on demand.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using an ESB like NServiceBus seems like a good solution to your problem. But based on your conceptual description, there's some things to consider. Let's go through your requirements step-by-step, using NServiceBus as a possible ESB solution:

> I have a service that clients can send messages to. The service is "Fire and Forget"--the most the client would get back is something that may say success or failure (success being that the message was received).

This is easily done with NServiceBus. You can Bus.Send(Message) from the client. If your client requires an answer, you can use Bus.Return(ErrorCode). You mention that "success being that the message was received". If you use an ESB like NServiceBus, [it's up to the messaging platform the deliver the message](http://www.nservicebus.com/ArchitecturalPrinciples.aspx). So, if your Bus.Send doesn't throw an exception, you can be sure that the message has been sent properly. Because of this you don't probably have to send success / failure messages back to the client.

> The handling/processing of each message is non-trivial, and may take up significant system resources. For this reason only X messages can be handled concurrently, where X is a configurable value (based on system specs, etc.). Incoming messages will be stored in queue until it's "their turn" to be handled.

When using NServiceBus, you can configure the the number of worker threads by setting the "NumberOfWorkerThreads" option. If your server has multiple cores / cpus, you can use this setting to balance the work load.

> For each client, messages must be handled in order (FIFO).

This is something that may cause problems depending on your requirements. ESBs in general don't promise to process [the messages in-order](http://www.udidahan.com/2008/01/01/podcast-message-ordering-is-it-cost-effective/), if they have many threads working on the messages. In a case of NServiceBus, you can send an array of messages from the client into the bus and [these will be processed in-order.](http://nservicebus.grouply.com/message/8170) Also, you can solve some of the in-order messaging problems by using [Sagas](http://www.nservicebus.com/Sagas.aspx).

> However, some clients may send many messages in succession (thousands or more), for example if they lost connectivity for a period of time

When using an ESB solution, your server doesn't have to be up for the client to work. Clients can still send messages and the server will start processing them as soon as it's back online. Here's a [small introduction on this.](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/NServiceBus-and-monitoring-the-queues.aspx)

> For this reason, messages must be handled in a round-robin fashion across clients--no client is allowed to gorge and no client is allowed to starve.

This isn't a problem because you've decided to use messages :)

> So the system will either have to be able to query the queue for a specific client, or create separate queues per client (automatically, since the clients won't be known at compile time) and pull from them in rotation.

Could you expand on this? I'm not sure of your design on this one.

Comment: See John's answer--along the lines of creating separate queues on demand.  I will add more info to my question shortly.  Thanks for your answer.